# Faster code for specific problem

Tags: performance-tuning

Sorry, but I need the following code much faster and I'm running out of ideas. I do appreciate any help. I post two of my fastest ideas (tab and mat), although they are not really fast. Thanks in advance.

```
Clear[bNum,nNum,weights,newMat,sortMat,tab];

bNum=20;
nNum=100;

weights=Table[RandomReal[{-10,10}],{b,1,bNum},{n,1,nNum}];
newMat=Table[RandomReal[{-10,10}],{b,1,bNum},{n,1,nNum}];
sortMat=Table[i,{i, -10, 10, 0.1}];

tab=Table[
Sum[weights[[k,i]]*If[newMat[[k,i]] <= sortMat[[j]],1.,0.],{i,1,nNum}],{k,1,bNum}, 
{j,1,Length[sortMat]}];//AbsoluteTiming

mat=Block[{k=1},
Reap[Do[
Sow[Table[Sum[weights[[k,i]]*If[newMat[[k,i]] <= sortMat[[j]],1.,0.],{i,1,nNum}],{j,1,Length[sortMat]}]];
k++,{bNum}]]][[2,1]];//AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Rephrase your question to be an actual question, format your code (press the golden question mark in the top right of the input text field to read about formatting, it leads to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help ), and explain what you are trying to do rather then just post a code snippet with the request of "make it faster".

Comment: To restate jVincent's plea: please state your **actual problem**, format your code, and then we can be more helpful...

Comment: You can compile it. There is one Wolfram help link http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CompilingMathematicaExpressions.html

Comment: Hi Chris, and welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange. Sorry if some of the first responses you received seem overly critical. We sometimes forget that new folks need some time to understand just how the site works. Don't forget to upvote good answers (and other people's questions) using the triangle above the number next to the post, and use the checkmark to "accept" the answer to your question that you think best answers it.

Comment: This is faster: Timing[tab2 = Transpose[Table[
  Map[Total,weights*UnitStep[sortMat[[j]]-newMat]], {j,Length[sortMat]}]];] In general you want to use Mathematica's list-based operations for this sort of thing.

Comment: Will `sortMat` always contain an evenly spaced list of numbers?  If so, a significant speedup is possible. Otherwise, the best solutions will likely first sort the rows of `newMat` and `weights` in parallel and accumulate the weights before doing any testing: that should get a few orders of magnitude speedup :-).

Comment: @whuber: yes the list contains always evenly spaced numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Updated with whuber's fix, and added `process3`

Murta showed Compile and whuber showed a great algorithm improvement.
Let me show some syntax tweaking.

whuber's `process` function can be written more efficiently and concisely like this:

```
process2[x_, w_, {y0_, dy_, ny_}] :=
  Module[{x0, w0},
    x0 = Ceiling[(x - y0)/dy] ~Clip~ {0, ny};
    x0 = Join[{0}, Sort @ x0, {ny}];
    w0 = {0} ~Join~ Accumulate[ w[[Ordering @ x]] ];
    Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {w0, Differences@x0}]
  ]
```

Your code producing the random tables can be made much more efficient, as there is a specific syntax within `RandomReal` (and `RandomInteger`, etc.) for this.

```
bNum = 200;
nNum = 100;
weights = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {bNum, nNum}];
newMat  = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {bNum, nNum}];
```

Timing comparison with `process`:

```
MapThread[process[#1, #2, {-10, 0.1, 201}] &, {newMat, weights}]; //Timing //First

MapThread[process2[#1, #2, {-10, 0.1, 201}] &, {newMat, weights}]; //Timing //First
```

> 0.0842
>
> 0.01744

(My code originally showed about a doubling of performance over whuber's.  It's now nearly 5X due to the poor performance of `Min[ny, Max[0, Ceiling[(# - y0)/dy]]] & /@ x` in the fix, which I handled with `Clip`.)

---

I decided to implement a form of the function that operates on `newMat` and `weights` directly, that is moving the outer `MapThread` inside the function.  This allows certain optimizations at the cost of additional memory consumption.

```
process3[x_, w_, {y0_, dy_, ny_}] :=
  Module[{xm, wm},
    xm = Ceiling[(x - y0)/dy] ~Clip~ {0, ny};
    xm = ArrayFlatten @ {{0, Sort /@ xm, ny}};
    wm = ArrayFlatten @ {{0, MapThread[Accumulate @ #2[[Ordering@#]] &, {x, w}]}};
    Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {#2, Differences@#}] & ~MapThread~ {xm, wm}
  ]

process3[newMat, weights, {-10, 0.1, 201}] //Timing //First
```

> 0.01496

Comment: Might as well do `FoldList[Plus, 0, w[[Ordering@x]]]` instead of `{0} ~Join~ Accumulate[w[[Ordering@x]]]`... :)

Comment: @J.M. prior experience suggests that will be slower, but I'll test it now.  Yup, slower, at least on version 7.

Comment: BTW: you don't need to generate `sortMat` anymore. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thank you very much for another great improvement.

Comment: Thank you: collectively, we're now up to about a factor of 150 improvement over the original. Perhaps the last challenge remaining would be to compile this code, thereby combining both ideas. `Compile` doesn't like the last step (of joining constant arrays of varying lengths). If there is a way to do this efficiently and get it compiled, possibly the timing can be improved further (but probably not dramatically).

Comment: @whuber you could also get a slight improvement processing all of `newMat` in `Floor[(x - y0)/dy + 1]` at once.

Comment: Good idea.  For simplicity, I decided at the outset to process the input row by row rather than comprehensively, but in some circumstances a little precomputation of this nature could save some time. Before going in such directions, we would want to find out the intended ranges of the input data sizes, such as values for `bNum`, `nNum`, and the length of `sortMat`. Those would indicate whether such measures would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 9):

As I have [advocated in another thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10029), usually the best way (by far) to speed up a calculation is first to improve the algorithm.  Then--if it remains necessary--you can focus on platform-specific methods to speed up execution.

Here, `newMat` and `weights` are viewed as lists of vectors to be processed in parallel and (according to a comment to the question) `sortMat` is really a sequence $(y_0, y_0 + dy, y_0 + 2 dy, \ldots, y_0 + (n-1) dy)$.  For each $y$ in this sequence, the algorithm seeks the sum of weights associated with elements $x$ of `newMat` less than or equal to $y$.

[To find those elements, we change the units of measurement of `x` and `sortMat` so that the new `sortMat` is the integral sequence $(1, 2, \ldots, n)$ and we sort `x` (and sort the weights in parallel with `x` to keep their association intact).  After these preliminaries, the integer part of any entry in `x` tells us precisely how many elements of `sortMat` are less than it.  Thus--work a few simple examples to check--the *differences* in this sorted, re-expressed `x` tell us how many times each cumulative weight ought to appear in the output.  The larger `sortMat` is relative to `x`, the more computation this approach saves.]

An efficient approach would capitalize on a preliminary sorting of `newMat` (which requires sorting the corresponding vector `weights` in parallel). Do this with `Ordering`.  This reduces the amount of computation to the length of each row of `newMat` rather than the length of `sortMat` and it reduces a triple nested loop to a double nested loop (which is the minimum possible, given that the output is a rank 2 array).

```
ClearAll[process];
process[x_, w_, {y0_, dy_, ny_}] := Module[{x0, w0, v, i, f},
   x0 = Min[ny, Max[0, Ceiling[(# - y0)/dy]]] & /@ x;
   x0 = {0}~Join~Sort[x0]~Join~{ny};
   w0 = {0}~Join~Accumulate[w[[Ordering[x]]]];
   f := Function[{v, i}, Flatten[ConstantArray[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ ({v, i}\[Transpose])]];
   f[w0, Differences[x0]]
   ];
```

Let's check the timing and the correctness of this solution.  Because it's much faster, let's make `newMat` have ten times as many rows as before:

```
bNum = 200;
nNum = 100;
weights = Table[RandomReal[{-10, 10}], {b, 1, bNum}, {n, 1, nNum}];
newMat = Table[RandomReal[{-10, 10}], {b, 1, bNum}, {n, 1, nNum}];
sortMat = Table[i, {i, -10, 10, 0.1}];
```

Now:

```
tab = Table[Sum[weights[[k, i]]*
      If[newMat[[k, i]] <= sortMat[[j]], 1., 0.], {i, 1, nNum}], 
          {k, 1, bNum}, {j, 1, Length[sortMat]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.2744732, Null}

and (describing `sortMat` with the list $(y_0, dy, n)$ = $(-10, 0.1, 201)$)

```
tab0 = MapThread[process[#1, #2, {-10, 0.1, 201}] &, {newMat, weights}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0920053, Null}

**It's 89 times faster, yet produces the same result to within floating point error:**

```
Plus @@ (Abs[Chop[#]] & /@ (Flatten[tab] - Flatten[tab0])) == 0.0
```

> True

*Now,* if you wish to speed up the improved algorithm with a compilation, go ahead.

---

#### Edit

The comments and a further chat session (linked in the comments) uncovered some implicit assumptions in the original solution and led to an improvement that more closely matches the original. The two algorithms are not completely identical when applied to machine-precision numbers, though, due to differences in how the values in `sortMat` are computed and compared to the values in `newMat`.  Testing indicates they do agree except when elements of `newMat` *appear* to equal elements of `sortMat`: an equality test might or might not return `True` in such cases.

Comment: I'd replace `If[newMat[[k, i]] <= sortMat[[j]], 1., 0.]` with `Boole[newMat[[k, i]] <= sortMat[[j]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. You do see that's in the *non-optimized* part, right?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Ah, right. After looking at the method in more detail, I think a judicious use of `Dot[]` might lead to a better route...

Comment: @J.M. I'd like to see another good use of `Dot`.  Please.

Comment: I suppose something like `Outer[First[#1].Boole[Thread[Last[#1] <= #2]] &, Transpose[{weights, newMat}], sortMat, 1]` or `MapThread[Table[#1.Boole[Thread[#2 <= k]], {k, sortMat}] &, {weights, newMat}]`, @Mr.Wizard

Comment: @whuber: thanks a lot for this impressive speed improvement. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks to all the others as well.

Comment: @whuber: I did compile it and it works just fine. Thanks again. However, I would very much appreciate if you could explain your idea behind the vector x0. I just can't get a grip on it.

Comment: I inserted a third paragraph outlining the idea.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the enlightenment. However, I still have trouble adapting the code once the values of `sortMat`have smaller range than the values in `newMat`. For example, if you change (in my previous example) `sortMat` to `sortMat=Table[i,{i, -9, 9, 0.1}];` the code breaks down.

Comment: Chris, I am surprised at that statement, because I *developed and tested this method on a much shorter version of `sortMat`.* Nevertheless, I went back and compared my results with yours using various ranges for `sortMat` and obtained *exactly* the same results as your code. Could you please then tell us precisely what "breaks down" means?  Is it possible you forgot to change the argument `{-10, 0.1, 201}` to `{-9, 0.1, 181}` to reflect the newer version of `sortMat`?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. If you change `sortMat` to `sortMat=Table[i,{i, -9, 9, 0.1}]` negative entries in `Differences[x0]` are generated. Thus, mapping the constant array produces an error. I have the arguments as they should be `{-9,0.1,181}`
.

Comment: I see the problem. Although sorting makes negative entries impossible, I assumed that `sortMat` would span the range of the x values. That assumption is reflected in prepending $0$ and appending `ny` in the first line of the solution. When this assumption is false--and I apologize for not pointing this out and implementing it in the code--you need to clamp the values of `x0` to the range from 0 to `ny`.  I'll insert that line.  (It doesn't change the timing at all, fortunately.)

Comment: Thank you. While trying to truly understand your code I worked with the following simple example:
`x = {1., 1.9, 1.6, 1.7, .5};
w = {.4, .3, .2, .05, .05};
ny = 20;
y0 = 0.4;
dy = .1;`
Executing `process[x, w, {y0, dy, ny}]`however, leads to a different result than my `tab` function using `newMat=x`and `weights=w`and 
`end = y0 + (ny - 1)*dy;
sortMat = Range[y0, end, dy];`
How can this be? It seems that I'm missing something.

Comment: That's a great way to test, Chris. The differences occur when some values of `x` appear to equal some values of `sortMat`. We are running into floating point error. To see this, set `x = {1, 19, 16, 17, 5}/10` and `ny = 20; y0 = 4/10; dy = 1/10` so that *MMA* uses exact arithmetic: you will find that `process` and your code now get exactly the same results.

Comment: I just tested it. Unfortunately, the results differ. I do also think that once the code is used in a compiled function the floating point issue will still be present, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6078/discussion-between-whuber-and-chris)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one demonstration on how to optimize your code using compile.
I see that you are not using the functional programin mindset yet, this could be improved in your code too, but here I will focus just on compile.

Here we create your original matrices:

```
Clear[bNum,nNum,weights,newMat,sortMat,tab];

bNum=20;
nNum=100;

weights = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {bNum, nNum}];
newMat = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {bNum, nNum}];
sortMat = Range[-10, 10, 0.1];
```

Now I created 3 exemples of your `tab` computation:

```
tab[weights_,newMat_,sortMat_]:=Module[{bNum,nNum},
    {bNum,nNum}=Dimensions[weights];
    Table[
            Sum[
                weights[[k,i]]*If[newMat[[k,i]]<=sortMat[[j]],1.,0.]
                ,{i,1,nNum}
                ]
            ,{k,1,bNum},{j,1,Length[sortMat]}
    ]
]

tabCompiled=Compile[{{weights,_Real,2},{newMat,_Real,2},{sortMat,_Real,1}},

    Module[{bNum,nNum},
    {bNum,nNum}=Dimensions[weights];
    Table[
            Sum[
                weights[[k,i]]*If[newMat[[k,i]]<=sortMat[[j]],1.,0.]
                ,{i,1,nNum}
                ]
            ,{k,1,bNum},{j,1,Length[sortMat]}
        ]
    ]
];

tabCompiledC=Compile[{{weights,_Real,2},{newMat,_Real,2},{sortMat,_Real,1}},

    Module[{bNum,nNum},
    {bNum,nNum}=Dimensions[weights];
    Table[
            Sum[
                weights[[k,i]]*If[newMat[[k,i]]<=sortMat[[j]],1.,0.]
                ,{i,1,nNum}
                ]
            ,{k,1,bNum},{j,1,Length[sortMat]}
        ]
    ]
    ,CompilationTarget->"C"
];
```

The first without compile, the second compiled, the third compiled in  C.
Compare the diferences:

```
tab[weights, newMat, sortMat]; // AbsoluteTiming
tabCompiled[weights, newMat, sortMat]; // AbsoluteTiming
tabCompiledC[weights, newMat, sortMat]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.833, Null}
{0.046, Null}
{0.016, Null}
```

I hope that it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a decent speed up with a little tweak of the method suggested in Daniel Lichtblau's comment, by transposing `newMat` and `weights` so that `Total` can be used more efficiently:

```
tab2 = Module[{nt = Transpose[newMat], wt = Transpose[weights]}, 
  Transpose[Total[UnitStep[# - nt] wt] & /@ sortMat]];
```

With the array sizes in the question this gives me a speedup factor of about 120.

The code can be dropped directly into `Compile` for another factor of 2:

```
c = Compile[{{newMat, _Real, 2}, {weights, _Real, 2}, {sortMat, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{nt = Transpose[newMat], wt = Transpose[weights]}, 
    Transpose[Total[UnitStep[# - nt] wt] & /@ sortMat]]];

tab3 = c[newMat, weights, sortMat];
```