# A better "VisibleSpectrum" function?

Tags: color, physics

Since [`ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]` is wrong](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11480/121), I would like to have a more accurate function to use.
Can this information be extracted from *Mathematica* itself?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*Notice:*

Simon Woods did just this months ago for an answer I missed:

- [Convert spectral distribution to RGB color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57389/convert-spectral-distribution-to-rgb-color/57457#57457)

---

It seems that it can.  By spelunking [`ChromaticityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChromaticityPlot.html) I found:

```
Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths

Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris
```

These are a list of wavelengths and their corresponding XYZ color values used by this plot command:

```
ChromaticityPlot["sRGB", Appearance -> {"VisibleSpectrum", "Wavelengths" -> True}]
```

[image]

We can therefore use them to generate a new color function:

```
ChromaticityPlot;  (* pre-load internals *)

newVisibleSpectrum =
  With[
    {colors =
      {Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths,
       XYZColor @@@ Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris}\[Transpose]},
    Blend[colors, #] &
  ];
```

A comparison with the old function:

```
ArrayPlot[
 {Range[385, 745]},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 AspectRatio -> 0.1,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> #
] & /@
  {"VisibleSpectrum", newVisibleSpectrum} // Column
```

[image]

589nm is now the bright sodium yellow that it should be:

```
Graphics[{newVisibleSpectrum @ 589, Disk[]}]
```

[image]

If you wish to integrate this into [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) see:

- [Is it possible to insert new colour schemes into ColorData?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57885/121)

---

As requested by J.M. red-green-blue plots for each function:

```
old = List @@@ Array[ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"], 361, 385];

new = List @@@ ColorConvert[Array[newVisibleSpectrum, 361, 385], "RGB"];

ListLinePlot[Transpose @ #,
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
   DataRange -> {385, 745}
] & /@ {old, new}
```

[image]

Clipping occurs during conversion to screen RGB; the `newVisibleSpectrum` function actually produces unclipped [`XYZColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XYZColor.html) data.  For example projected over gray:

```
newVSgray = 
  With[{colors = 
     Array[{#, Blend[{newVisibleSpectrum@#, ColorConvert[GrayLevel[.66], "XYZ"]}, 
         0.715]} &, 361, 385]}, Blend[colors, #] &];

ListLinePlot[
 List @@@ ColorConvert[Array[newVSgray, 361, 385], "RGB"] // Transpose, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, DataRange -> {385, 745}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Which corresponds to the plot:

```
ArrayPlot[{Range[385, 745]}, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.1, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> newVSgray, 
 Background -> GrayLevel[0.567]]
```

[image]

cf. `"VisibleSpectrum"` similarly over gray blended in `XYZColor` and `RGBColor` respectively:

[image]
[image]

Note that neither rendering of this spectrum has the vibrancy of `newVisibleSpectrum`.

Comment: It seems the internal functions are only available after you call `ChromaticityPlot` once. Is that normal?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, it's common with many internal functions and I should have thought to mention it.

Comment: +1 Nice. Though spelunking `ChromaticityPlot` is [so last year](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57457/862)  :-)

Comment: @Simon Gah!  How'd I miss that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I don't know, but I'm glad you did.

Comment: If you have time to spare, could you edit your post to include plots of the red, green, and blue components?

Comment: @J.M. Please let me know if that is what you meant.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Unfortunately I can't upvote again, so I'll just offer my observation that `Blend[]` seems to be interpolating in XYZ space here, and I think that's part of the reason why the new visible spectrum gradient looks great.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wonder if it might be better to convert the colors in `"VisibleSpectrum"` to XYZ before being fed to `Blend[]`. Tho, that should probably be posted in the other question… :)

Comment: @J.M. With ``Blend[DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument["VisibleSpectrum"]/.c_RGBColor:>ColorConvert[c,"XYZ"],#]&`` I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/SbBWLmt.png). The difference is almost imperceptible.

Comment: @Alexey, that's too bad… I guess that particular gradient really is unsalvageable. :(

Comment: @J.M. the `"VisibleSpectrum"` data is already clipped; you can't un-clip it by converting to `XYZColor`.  It does change how the colors are rendered in screen RGB but either way the clipping remains.  I added a pair of examples to the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Converting ``Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris`` into `"RGB"` does change the appearance but not too much; unfortunately the basic set of colors of `"VisibleSpectrum"` is simply wrong.

Comment: That gradient is *very* bad, and that makes me dubious about the black body one as well. I'll try to see where/how they are implemented and fix them. I should also read here more often...
(btw if the color matching functions are such coveted material I may put them in a decent context or push for them to be in System altogether)

Comment: @Batracos Which one do you mean?  `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]` or the one I extracted here? (`newVisibleSpectrum`)

Comment: @Batracos, re: blackbody - see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57389).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I meant `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]`.
@J.M. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 9):

(with many thanks to halirutan and kirma for their kind assistance)

Here's a different take. In [this article](http://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/01/), piecewise Gaussian functions that approximate the CIE color matching functions are presented. For this answer, instead of just taking the coefficients from the paper directly, I used their proposed model in `FindFit[]`, using a 1 nm tabulation of the 1931 CMFs from [here](http://www.cvrl.org/database/data/cmfs/ciexyz31_1.csv) as the data the proposed model is being fitted to. Here are the resulting functions:

```
SetAttributes[{cieX, cieY, cieZ}, Listable];
cieX[λ_] := {0.36263412, 1.05593554, -0.2122116}.Exp[
            -MapThread[(λ - #1) Piecewise[{{#2, λ < #1}, {#3, True}}] &,
                       {{440.76797, 599.44051, 493.87482},
                        {0.066588512, 0.027633445, 0.048888466},
                        {0.020005468, 0.032068622, 0.039095442}}]^2/2]

cieY[λ_] := {0.82087906, 0.28579841}.Exp[
            -MapThread[(λ - #1) Piecewise[{{#2, λ < #1}, {#3, True}}] &,
                       {{568.78966, 530.87379},
                        {0.021328878, 0.061294726},
                        {0.024693511, 0.032178136}}]^2/2]

cieZ[λ_] := {1.21649968, 0.68126275}.Exp[
            -MapThread[(λ - #1) Piecewise[{{#2, λ < #1}, {#3, True}}] &,
                       {{436.96247, 459.03433},
                        {0.084453906, 0.038519512},
                        {0.027788061, 0.072502761}}]^2/2]
```

In version 10, one can of course directly do `Through[XYZColor[cieX, cieY, cieZ][λ]]`; for older versions, you will have to do the conversion to sRGB yourself, like so:

```
(* gamma correction *)
sRGBGamma = Function[x, With[{z = Abs[x]},
                             Sign[x] Piecewise[{{12.92 z, z <= 0.0031308}},
                                               1.055 z^(1/2.4) - 0.055]],
                     Listable];

myVisibleSpectrum[λ_] :=
     RGBColor @@ Clip[sRGBGamma[{{3.2404542, -1.5371385, -0.49853141},
                                 {-0.96926603, 1.8760108, 0.041556017},
                                 {0.055643431, -0.20402591, 1.0572252}} .
                                Through[{cieX, cieY, cieZ}[λ]]], {0, 1}]
```

Here are the corresponding gradient and component plots for `myVisibleSpectrum[]`:
[image: myVisibleSpectrum demonstration]

Here's the result of coloring a `Disk[]` with `myVisibleSpectrum[589]`:
[image: sodium yellow?]

The approximation looks good, at least with my eyes.

This replicates the internal data (as used in `newVisibleSpectrum`) quite well:

```
cieXYZ = Through[XYZColor[cieX, cieY, cieZ][#]] &;

{d1, d2} = Transpose /@ Table[List @@ fn[λ], {fn, {cieXYZ, newVisibleSpectrum}},
                              {λ, 385, 745}];

Show[ListLinePlot[d1, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Hue[0.55, 0.5, 1]],
                  PlotTheme -> "Pastel", InterpolationOrder -> 3],
     ListLinePlot[d2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]]]
```

[image: comparison of tabulated CMF with analytic fit]

---

**Alternatives**

I had already discussed Bruton's algorithm in [my other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11484). I'm not sure how to convert wavelengths to the colors used in Sam's answer, but here is how to see them in *Mathematica*:

```
DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1/8}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
            ColorFunction -> Function[t, RGBColor @@ Haversine[2 π t - {π, 5 π/3, π/3}]]]
```

[image: Sam's color gradient]

Comment: Thanks for answering.  It seems you've replicated the internal data quite well.  I'll assume your gedanken mma isn't up to direct `.PNG` output yet so I included a plot to show this.

Comment: No, I'm using a borrowed computer for now. :) (though it only has version 8). Thanks for putting in the plot!

Answer (score 5):

Here's my mathematical rainbow spectrum plot.

I'm not sure how accurate it is, and I did not attempt to calibrate it with measured data; but it's the smoothest, best looking spectrum I've seen, so I thought I would post it here.

[image: rainbow spectrum]

Large images:  http://sam.nipl.net/pix/spectrum.png  http://sam.nipl.net/pix/spectrum2.png

Reasoning:

- All colours in the rainbow spectrum should be shown with equal intensity.
- In RGB, yellow(1,1,0) has greater intensity than red(1,0,0) or green(0,1,0).
- So, we need a less intense yellow for our rainbow.  I used cosines.
- The rainbow is an octave of light, from 400THz-800Thz, or 750nm-375nm.
- We can see 12 rainbow colours, like the 12 musical notes.
- The refractive index varies with the wavelength of light.
- The rainbow is a uniform plot over wavelength (not freq. or "note").
- Several "rainbow echoes" are seen, due to resonance with higher octaves.

Here is a picture of rainbow echoes, these are due I suppose to harmonic resonance:

[image: rainbow with echoes]

Here is the code, it's not in Mathematica (sorry!):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/cz --

use b

Main()
    space(1900,100)
    origin(w_2, h_2)
    rainbow_init()

    for(x, 0.0, w)
        rainbow_colour(x/w)
        line(x, 0, x, h)
    paint()

    if args && cstr_eq(arg[0], "-s"):
        plot_12_tones()

num rb_red_angle, rb_green_angle, rb_blue_angle
num rb_red_power, rb_green_power, rb_blue_power

rainbow_init()
    rb_red_angle = deg2rad(0)
    rb_green_angle = deg2rad(120)
    rb_blue_angle = deg2rad(-120)

    rb_red_power = 1
    rb_green_power = 1
    rb_blue_power = 1

colour rainbow_colour(num h)
    num y = pow(2, h)-1
    num a = 2*pi*y
    num r = rb_red_power * (cos((a-rb_red_angle))+1)/2
    num g = rb_green_power * (cos((a-rb_green_angle))+1)/2
    num b = rb_blue_power * (cos((a-rb_blue_angle))+1)/2
    return rgb(r, g, b)

plot_12_tones()
    black()
    for(i, 0, 12+1):
        num freq = pow(2, i/12.0)
        num wl = 2 - 1/freq * 2
        num x = wl*w
        x = iclamp(x, 0, w-1)
        line(x, 0, x, 2)
        line(x, h, x, h-3)
```

Comment: Sam, welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange.  I appreciate you posting this despite what I am about to say: if you do not have *Mathematica* an/or are unfamiliar with its language it will be difficult for you to meaningfully participate here.  If you choose to participate you should focus on clear English descriptions of algorithms or approaches rather than code in another language.

Comment: Subjectively the yellow in your photo looks more intense than the one in your smooth spectrum; I take it your intent is *not* to replicate the photo but instead to produce a pleasingly smooth gradient, correct?

Comment: Mr.Wizard, yes that's correct.  Perhaps I'll have a go at translating it into Mathematica...

Comment: The "echoes" are called supernumerary bows.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Supernumerary_rainbow

Comment: These supernumerary bows have nothing whatsoever to do with "harmonic resonance," at least as such words mean.