# How can I plot visible spectrum?

Tags: graphics, visualization, physics

I have a data with wavelength and intensity and I draw these graph with excel.[image: wavelength- intensity graph]

then how can i make this into specturm like below?[image: spectrum]

Comment: You can use [How to plot an emission spectrum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85990/5478) But I suppose you are interested in a profile not in a set of lines, right?

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: my raw data is in my spread sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KoDbffY32324vJJ08716fuLHVYi_lEh-cg4sIZViagU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You might consider using `FindPeaks` along with any of the solutions in the thread Kuba linked to. I'm marking this as a dupe; if you think the code there doesn't solve your problem, edit this question to explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with some generated sample data.  You will need to adjust the colour function and the scaling of the data for your application.  Here I used the builtin colour function `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]`, which takes values between 380 and 750.  You probably need to tweak this, since your range is 300 to 1000.

Sample data:

```
data = Table[{x, 
    Sum[Exp[-0.1 (x - mid)^2]/mid, {mid, {400, 500, 600}}]}, {x, 380, 
    750}];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Rescale data, so intensities are between 0 and 1.

```
max = Max[data[[All, 2]]];
data = {#1, #2/max} & @@@ data;
```

Build a nice colour function:

```
cf = Blend[{Black, Blend[{White, ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][#1]}]}, #2] &;
```

This has two parameters: the first one is the wavelength, the second is the intensity.  The extra blending with `White` is to improve visibility.

```
ArrayPlot[{cf @@@ data}, AspectRatio -> 1/10, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: my raw data is in my spread sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KoDbffY32324vJJ08716fuLHVYi_lEh-cg4sIZViagU/edit?usp=sharing