# Integrating over colors

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation, color

I'm trying to compute the following integral:

$$\int_{380  \, \mathrm{nm}}^{700  \, \mathrm{nm}}\mathbf{RGB}(\mathrm{Hue}(\lambda))\frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{\lambda^4}$$

where $\mathbf{RBG}$ takes in a `Hue` and outputs a vector like `{0., 1., 1.}`.

This is how I've tried to implement this:

```
lambdaToHue[wavelength_] := Hue[-.8/(700 - 380) wavelength + 1.75]
```

which takes wavelengths into Hues, (evaluating it on 380 gives purple, on 700 gives red). Then

```
hueToRBG[hue_] := Table[ColorConvert[hue, "RGB"][[i]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

takes Hues into vectors, so e.g. evaluating it on `lambdaToHue[380]` gives `{0.8, 0., 1.}`. So I can put in values for wavelength and get numbers from `hueToRBG[wavelengthToHue[wavelengths]]`. So I should be able to compute an integral, like

```
NIntegrate[hueToRBG[lambdaToHue[l]]/l^4,{l,380,700}]
```

but in reality Mathematica complains:

```
"The integrand Hue[1.75 -0.0025\ l] has evaluated to \
non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with \
boundaries {{380,700}}"
```

How can I get mathematica to actually just compute the integral of this function which takes numbers into lists of numbers? It works fine, e.g., for

```
NIntegrate[{x,Sin[x],Sqrt[x]}/x^4,{x,2,4}].
```

Much thanks!

Comment: Better use `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]` instead of `Hue`. Should be more related to the actual physical colors...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks I'll be sure to use that! But I still have the same issue with Mathematica complaining that I'm trying to integrate over colors without noticing that I'm actually summing vectors

Comment: I have found an extremely hacky way of doing this; waiting for a better solution: integrate numerically using `Total /@ Transpose[(Table[
     ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][\[Lambda]] /. 
      RGBColor[a___] -> {a}, {\[Lambda], 380, 750, 0.1}]*
    Table[0.1/\[Lambda]^2.5, {\[Lambda], 380, 750, 0.1}])]`

Comment: `Sum [.1  1/\[Lambda]^4 Apply[List, 
   ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][\[Lambda]]], {\[Lambda], 380, 750, 
  0.1}]` evaluates to `{1.56038*10^-9, 1.46384*10^-9, 2.74953*10^-9}` **black**

Comment: Perhaps: `f[\[Lambda]_?NumericQ, 
  k_] := (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][\[Lambda]])[[k]];NIntegrate[f[\[Lambda], #]/\[Lambda]^4, {\[Lambda], 380, 700}] & /@ 
 Range[3]`?

Comment: @Diffycue In case you want to realistically simulate the resulting color of Rayleigh scattering be aware that RGB does not behave linearly with respect to wavelength. A better approach is usually to get `xyz` values first by [using the CIE sensitivity functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#Computing_XYZ_from_spectral_data) instead of your `RGB` function in your integral and then in a second step [convert from `xyz` to RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#Construction_of_the_CIE_XYZ_color_space_from_the_Wright%E2%80%93Guild_data).

Comment: Mathematica also accepts xyz tristimulus data directly via [`XYZColor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XYZColor.html) which saves the last conversino step to RGB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73161/), the CIE sensitivity functions are built-in, yet *undocumented*:

```
ChromaticityPlot; (* force autoload *)
xyz = Interpolation[Transpose[{Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths, #}]] & /@ 
      Transpose[Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris];
```

However,

```
MinMax[Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths]
   {{385, 745}}
```

its coverage is a little off from the desired integral in the OP, so I'll just demonstrate the integral from $385$ to $700\,\mathrm{nm}$. (If wanted, you can download [a finer tabulation with more coverage](http://www.cvrl.org/database/data/cmfs/ciexyz31_1.csv).)

From here, we can use the sRGB conversion functions from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86962), and then use `NIntegrate[]` with the setting `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`:

```
(* gamma correction *)
sRGBGamma = Function[x, With[{z = Abs[x]},
                             Sign[x] Piecewise[{{12.92 z, z <= 0.0031308}},
                                               1.055 z^(1/2.4) - 0.055]],
                     Listable];

NIntegrate[Clip[#, {0, 1}]/λ^4, {λ, 385, 700},
           Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"] & /@ 
sRGBGamma[{{3.2404542, -1.5371385, -0.49853141},
           {-0.96926603, 1.8760108, 0.041556017},
           {0.055643431, -0.20402591, 1.0572252}}.Through[xyz[λ]]]
   {1.48544*10^-9, 1.36666*10^-9, 2.28451*10^-9}
```